# Entity framework throwing Invalid object for table that no longer exists on savechanges for other table

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-database-first

I am writing an MVC app over an existing database. I set up all my models and created my own dbcontext file and started doing some controller and view work, then someone discovered a table in the underlying SQL database was created by mistake and deleted it. Now when my controller executes a dbcontext.savechanges() for a different table, I get an error message >"Invalid object name 'deletedTable'"

That table was never used in my app, and doing a simple find in Visual Studio for the entire solution, 'deletedTable' isn't found anywhere.

I suspect somewhere along the line entity framework took a snapshot of the underlying database and now that is out of synch with the real database, however I don't know where that snapshot is or how to force it to refresh.

Or I'm completely wrong.

Comment: Just to be sure, you created the database code-first?

Comment: Kind of. The database already existed and had data. I manually created the context and model and am in general trying not to let EF create anything for me or mess with the db's schema. I'm not using EDMX or any of the other data visualization tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this basically magically fixed itself when I came back to it a few days later. I suppose whatever had the snapshot was just in memory somewhere.

**EDIT**

Actually turned out what I thought was magic was someone on the DB team finding a SQL trigger that was still trying to act on the deleted table, once that trigger was removed the problem was solved.